# How can I listen for when an attribute in a Bookshelf.js model is updated?

Tags: node.js, orm, bookshelf.js

I'm using Bookshelf.js. I want to listen for when a specific attribute in one of my models is updated. If it is, I want to run a function. How can I listen to the updates on the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
const User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users',

  initialize() {
    this.on('updated', (model) => {
      // This is fired after a model is updated
    })
  }
})
```

Note that this will not fire every time you change an attribute on your model by using `.set()`, but only when the model is saved to the database using `model.save()`.